# How to escape two single quotes in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

E.g: `Code=''`. If I use `Code =''''`, in the result I'm getting only one quote.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the current start and end quotes. Then double each quote supposed to be a part of the string value.

```
Code = ''''''
```

Or you can perhaps use a Unicode string literal:

```
Code = U&'\0027\0027'
```

Comment: I am getting three quotes in the result set instead of two

Comment: Very strange... What happens if you type 5 of them?

Answer (score 0):

More information in your qustion would be helpful. Which OS or where exactly you execute it.
Here is a working example from a Db2 command line:

```
db2 create table str(text varchar(20))
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 "insert into str values '''''' "
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 select * from str

TEXT
--------------------
''

1 record(s) selected.
```

Note the double quotes round the SQL to avoid shell interactions/reactions.