# Replacing single quote in a stored procedure call using replace

Tags: sql, db2

I have a call to a stored procedure (db2) and if a string has a single quote in it, it is breaking with an error of "Invalid Token". I know the solution is to replace the single quote to two single quotes. I am trying to use "replace" and getting an error of "Token S was not valid". Is this how "replace" should be used?

```
CALL my_store_proc ('xyz', 'US', 'MAIL', replace('Joe's',''','''''), 'zipcode' )
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use `CALL my_store_proc ('xyz', 'US', 'MAIL', $variableForJoe$, 'zipcode' )?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape two single quotes in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240066/how-to-escape-two-single-quotes-in-db2)

Comment: @mustaccio, It is not a duplicated, I am trying to replace single quote in a store procedure call,  its a little different than trying to escape a certain character in a way that the question you mentioned is asking.

Comment: No it isn't. It's the same SQL language.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the quote inside the literals also viz:

```
CALL my_store_proc ('xyz', 'US', 'MAIL', replace('Joe''s',''',''''') , 'zipcode' )
```

just for syntax, But depending on your intentions, you may need more quotes:

```
CALL my_store_proc ('xyz', 'US', 'MAIL',  replace('Joe''s','''',''''''), 'zipcode' )
```

Comment: The issue is, the value "joe's" is entered dynamically be the user, it could be "mary's" or any other string with single quote, I thought I could be  filtered on the fly.

Comment: @Andre you really _don't_ want to stick unsanitized user input into SQL statements; read about SQL injection.

Comment: I do understand that, I am simplifying things   here and thinking that "replace" could make my life easier.  I think that if you know you are going to get a string with single quote that "replace" could do the job. So there is no function in SQL that could do this on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the procedure wrong...

You don't mention where/how your calling your stored proc.  But ODBC, JDBC ect all have a method that allows you to set parameter values from a variable for a stored procedure call.

Using one of those methods rather than simply building a string is the preferred method of calling.

Comment: Can you explain why the call to the procedure is wrong? I am using ODBC to connect with Perl.