# escaping string quotes in sql insert query

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, db2

I am trying to allow people to input descriptions to a certain product, and this will be done through a dashboard, so I will not know in advance what a user will be inserting. however, It is required that the user will be able to insert a description like: `this item is 10" wide`. however, in sql (db2), it sees that as a string ending delimiter, which makes sense, but I cannot seem to find a way around this.

sometimes people may put `item1 is 10" wide and 3' tall`, again with multiple quotes in there where db2 would see that as an issue.

my query for the insert is standard, I've included it below"

```
var submitEdit =
      "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET (ITEM, PRICE, SIZES, DESCRIPTION, IMAGE) = ('" +
      req.query.item +
      "', '" +
      req.query.price +
      "', '" +
      size +
      "', '" +
      req.query.description +
      "', '" +
      image_url + "') WHERE ITEM = '" +
      req.query.ogItem +
      "'";
```

also, I know this query is easy access to sql injection, so I will be changing it eventually, but I would like to figure this out first lol!

thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: I think you need to learn about parameters so you are not munging SQL strings with such values, exposing your code to syntax errors and SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Run an escaping function before. SQL allows to use repeated single / double quotes to escape those quotes. Your INSERT statement is NOT standard. It is overly complex and insecure and should not be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape two single quotes in DB2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240066/how-to-escape-two-single-quotes-in-db2)

Comment: Don't "figure this out first" before using prepared statements. It would be wasted effort. The problem will go away if you use the correct coding practice. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html